# Tensorflow loss function no gradient provided

Tags: tensorflow, gradient, loss-function, loss, tensorflow-hub

Currently I try to code my own loss function, but when returning the result (a tensor that consists of a list with the loss values) I get the following error:

```
ValueError: No gradients provided for any variable: ['conv2d/kernel:0', 'conv2d/bias:0', 'conv2d_1/kernel:0', 'conv2d_1/bias:0', 'dense/kernel:0', 'dense/bias:0', 'dense_1/kernel:0', 'dense_1/bias:0', 'dense_2/kernel:0', 'dense_2/bias:0'].
```

However in tutorials and in their docs they also use `tf.recude_mean` and when using it like them (they showed how to code `mse` loss function) I dont get the error, so it seems that I am missing something

My code:

```
gl = tfa.losses.GIoULoss()
def loss(y_true, y_pred):
        batch_size = y_true.shape[0]
        # now contains 32 lists (a batch) of bbxs -> shape is (32, 7876)
        bbx_true = y_true.numpy()

        # now contains 32 lists (a batch) of bbxs here we have to double access [0] in order to get the entry itself 
        # -> shape is (32, 1, 1, 7876)
        bbx_pred = y_pred.numpy()

        losses = []
        curr_true = []
        curr_pred = []
        for i in range(batch_size):
            curr_true = bbx_true[i] 
            curr_pred = bbx_pred[i][0][0]


            curr_true = [curr_true[x:x+4] for x in range(0, len(curr_true), 4)]
            curr_pred = [curr_pred[x:x+4] for x in range(0, len(curr_pred), 4)]

            if len(curr_true) == 0:
                curr_true.append([0., 0.,0.,0.])

            curr_loss = gl(curr_true, curr_pred)

            losses.append(curr_loss)

        return tf.math.reduce_mean(losses, axis=-1)
```

Basically I want to achive `bounding box regression` and because of that I want to use the `GIoUloss` loss function. Because my model outputs 7896 neurons (the max amount of bounding boxes I want to predict according to my training set times 4) and the gioloss function needs the input as an array of lists with 4 elements each, I have to perform this transformation.

How do I have to change my code in order to also build up a `gradient`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Numpy don't provide autograd functions so you need to have Tensorflow tensors exclusively in your loss (otherwise the gradient is lost during backpropagation). So avoid using `.numpy()` and use the tensorflow operators and slicing on tensoflow tensors instead.

Comment: Could you please help me a little bit so transform this into tensorflow operations I dont really know how this should be possible, since I call an external loss function.... Btw. I am compiling in eager mode

Comment: check `tf.reshape` I think it is the main important function you miss here. Check also `tf.concat` to concatenation